# Biblatex and import package

Tags: biblatex

I have the following: one file as a preamble (ccc.tex) and two other files that share that preamble. One of the files is the main file (aaa.tex), and the other I use it to generate particular parts of the final document (e.g., figures, tables, etc.).

The structure is as follows:

```
folderA
|
|__ ccc.tex
|__ aaa.tex
|__ folderB
    |
    |__ bbb.tex
```

the files' content is as follows:

ccc.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib} % or
%\bibliography{biblio}
```

aaa.tex

```
\input{ccc}

\begin{document}

\cite{test:2000}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

bbb.tex

```
\RequirePackage{import}
\subimport{../}{ccc}

%\addbibresource{../biblio.bib} % uncomment on or the other to work
%\bibliography{../biblio}

\begin{document}

some text~\cite{test:2000}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

So my question is: is it possible to use `biblatex` without needing to specify `\addbibresource{../biblio.bib}` or `\bibliography{../biblio}` in bbb.tex?

Note that, I tried the previous approach with other packages (e.g., `acro`) and it worked without the need to change anything in the bbb.tex.

Answer (score 4):

The following work-flow did it for me

- Make sure you are in `folderA/folderB`, i.e. `cd folderA/folderB`
- Call `pdflatex bbb`, you'll get the temp files in `folderA/folderB` next to `bbb.tex`
- Call Biber `biber --input-directory=.. bbb`, that tells Biber to also look in `..`, i.e. `folderA` for files it can't find in the current directory, in particular `../biblio.bib` is found
- Call `pdflatex bbb` again

Alternatively

- Go to `folderA`
- Call `pdflatex -output-directory=folderB bbb`
- Call `biber bbb`
- `pdflatex -output-directory=folderB bbb`

also works (on MikTeX, I didn't test with TeX live).

---

Biber goes searching for `.bib` files as follows

1. Absolute filename
2. In the `--input-directory`, if specified
3. In the `--output-directory`, if specified
4. Relative to current directory
5. In the same directory as the control file
6. Using `kpsewhich` for supported formats, if available

The  `.bcf` is searched for similarly, but of course the step 5 is missing.

Naturally the problem was that if you call `biber` in `folderA/folderB` the relative file name of your `.bib` file is `../biblio.bib`. While `import` patches certain commands such as `\in­put`, `\in­clude` and `\in­clude­graph­ics` to be aware of the changing path if they are called from within a `\subimport`, there is no interface that tells `biblatex` to prefix all paths in `\addbibresource` commands it gets from `subimport` with `../`.